# Página de Contato funciona em GitHub Pages?

Tags: aplicação-web, github

Ao elaborar um simples protótipo de página para contato, eu lembrei que existe a possibilidade do projeto ser hospedado pelos servidores do GitHub.

#### Exemplo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas também lembrei que a hospedagem com o GitHub somente da suporte a processamento Front-End ou seja, esse formulário de contato não funcionará já que dele deveria ser feito com uma linguagem que roda no lado do servidor, como o **PHP** por exemplo.

## Dúvida

É possível fazer funcionar um formulário de contato desses mesmo ele sendo hospedado no GitHub Pages?

Caso **não** seja possível, existe alguma alternativa **com custo zero** para resolver esse problema?

Comment: Até onde sei o github pages hospeda apenas conteúdo estático(html, js, css), portanto, você não vai conseguir executar nada relacionado a backend. Você pode combinar github pages (caso você não queira gastar com domínio) com uma máquina ec2 dentro do free tier(1 ano grátis) da AWS(ou hospedar tudo lá mesmo). Na AWS você também consegue soluções permanentes com o custo bem baixo(AWS Lambda + API Gateway + S3).

Comment: Esse custo bem baixo da pra chegar a zero? realmente não queria ter gasto com hospedagem e nem com nome de domínio, na verdade eu estou propondo entregar o projeto com custo zero. É possível?

Comment: O free tier da aws te da 1 ano com o custo zero. Você pode montar uma api e hospedar em uma máquina ec2, daí você faz requests através do js da sua página no githubpages pra mandar email. Já rodei aplicações com a stack serverless(api gateway + lambda) da aws com custo mensal extremamente baixo (menos de $3). Da uma olhada em outros provedores de cloud, devem oferecer free tier ou custo bem baixo também.

Comment: Eu creio que sim, seja de algum modo possível fazer, sem nem precisar de lado servidor. Baseando-se na capacidade de se editar um arquivo do próprio GitHub através da API deles. Ou então mandar mensagem via `Messenger` para si mesmo usando a API do Facebook. O problema é que, como é tudo servido estaticamente, então o processamento precisa ser feito no browser e, portanto, a informação precisa estar disponível para quem baixar a página (claro, pode estar criptografado, mas você também precisa fornecer como descriptografar também)

Answer (score 1):

O propósito do GitHub Pages é servir de repositório para documentação de códigos hospedados no GitHub, utilizando-se de arquivos markdown, que são transformados em arquivos estáticos.
A ideia não é ter um espaço para homologação de uma aplicação e nem mesmo hospedagem de uma, mesmo sendo possível fazere uma usando SPA, Single Page Application.

Se você está desenvolvedo uma aplicação e que validá-la, use alguns dos serviços de nuvem tais como Azure ou AWS, que oferecem pelo período de um ano, para novas contas, um valor mensal para ser consumidor. O primeiro pode ser acesso por este link [azure.com/free](http://azure.com/free).

Se for muito complicado neste momento, existem serviços ainda mais simplestas, por exemplo: [heroku.com](https://www.heroku.com/).

Comment: Muito boa a dica, agradeço pelos links =) na verdade, como os projeto são estáticos eu pensei que pudesse usar o páginas do github, não existe nenhum tipo de processamento, até eu lembrar que existe a páginas de contato.